# Perfect set of irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F=\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}B_{1/2^n}(r_n)\right)^c,$ where $\{r_1,r_2,...\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}.$  Is it possible to know wheter $F$ is perfect? Can modify the construction to produce a perfect set?

For the first question I try the following: The boundary of $B_{1/2^n}(r_n)$ are rational the numbers that have your $B_{1/2^j}(r_j)$ and so on. Therefore this sequence of the boundary can converge to a point of F. Is correct?

The second part I try to change the $\varepsilon_n=\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{2})^n}$ so the boundary of the ball are irrational number and this number can not be a boundary of another ball. With this property I conclude that $F$ is perfect?

Comment: Is $B_a(b)$ the open ball of radius $a$ and center $b$?

Comment: @Gae.S.: Yes, it is.

Comment: I don't quite trust my understanding of what you expect by the question "Can modify the construction to produce a perfect set?", specifically if you're asking, like you suggested afterwards, if there is a sequence of radii $\varepsilon_\bullet$ such that $F_{\varepsilon,r}$ for all enumerations $r_\bullet$ of $\Bbb Q$, or if you're also asking if there is an enumeration $r_\bullet$ of $\Bbb Q$ such that $F_{\varepsilon, r}$ for $\varepsilon_n=2^{-n}$. continues...

Comment: However, I am quite confident that for any $\varepsilon_n\searrow 0$ you could find an enumeration $r_\bullet:\Bbb N\to \Bbb Q$ such that $F_{\varepsilon,r}$ has an isolated point. Essentially, select some $a\notin \Bbb Q$ and consider the subsequence $\varepsilon_{2^{n+1}}$ and assign $r_{2^{n+1}}$ in a way such that there is some $s>a$ such that $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_{\varepsilon_{2^{n+1}}}(r_{2^{n+1}})=(a,s)$. The, do the same with $\varepsilon_{3^{n+1}}$ to obtain that $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_{\varepsilon_{3^{n+1}}}(r_{3^{n+1}})=(t,a)$ for some $t<a$. continues...

Comment: Then, assign the subsequence $\{\varepsilon_{k_n}\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of the remaining radii to the remaining rational numbers in a way such that $a\notin \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_{\varepsilon_{k_n}}\left(r_{k_n}\right)$. You should be able to do with an ideal [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3370083/239203).

Comment: At the end of the "I don't quite understand" comment there should be "or if you're also asking if there is an enumeration $r_\bullet$ of $\Bbb Q$ such that $F_{\varepsilon,r}$ *is perfect* for $\varepsilon_n=2^{-n}$".